# Getting a random cell from excel file using c#.net Interop framework consoleApp

Tags: c#, excel, random

Getting a random cell from excel file using c#.net framework consoleApp so I tried this but it gives me this exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800A03EC'

```
Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\Projects\\ExcelSingleValue\\kTest.xlsx");
_Worksheet excelSheet = excelBook.Sheets[1];
Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

int rows = excelRange.Rows.Count;
int cols = excelRange.Columns.Count;

Random randomName = new Random(); 
Console.WriteLine((excelRange.Cells[randomName.Next(rows),1].Value2.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close...

Note that `randomName.Next(rows)` can return zero.  If it does then `.Cells[randomName.Next(rows),1]` will give you the error you see.

If your sheet has nothing on it then rows will always equal 1 and you have a 50% chance of the random number being zero.

**Solution**: Set the minimum value to 1 like this: `Next(1, rows)`

```
Console.WriteLine((excelRange.Cells[randomName.Next(1, rows),1].Value2.ToString()));
```